# Switch to the developer mode Magento 2

Tags: magento2, development, developer-mode

I just installed Magento 2 and I want to set the developer mode. But when I ran `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`, the command gives an error:

> catalogWidget/Model/Rule can not be deleted.

It's not changing the mode from default to developer.

Comment: please remove first var folder from root
and try again

Answer (score 4):

Here is 3 ways to change Magento 2 to developer mode

**1. Command line**

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

**2. Config file *app/etc/env.php***

Find line

```
'MAGE_MODE' => 'default'
```

Change to

```
'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer'
```

**3. Virtual Host**

apache2

```
SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer
```

nginx

```
set $MAGE_MODE developer;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set developer mode either from command line or change from the file

> Command :- php bin/Magento deploy:mode:set developer
>
> **File** : Open **env.php** at ( app/etc/env.php ) and find application mode 
>       and change default to developer mode
>             -- **MAGE_MODE' => 'default'** to **MAGE_MODE' => 'developer'**

Answer (score 1):

You can change mode using command, using .htaccess or set manually from env.php

1. Using Command

   ```
   php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
   ```
2. Open .htaccess file from magento root directory and uncomment below code by removing #

   ```
   #   SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer
   ```
3. Manually from app/etc/env.php

   Open file Magento/app/etc/env.php and find

   ```
   'MAGE_MODE' => 'default'
   ```

   and change it to

   ```
   'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

we can enable developer mode

Goto app/etc/ and open env.php

and change current application mode by  `'MAGE_MODE' => 'default'` to `'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer'`

Comment: php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Answer (score 0):

There are probably some generated files in `var/generation` and `pub/static` that you don't have permissions to delete. When switching to developer mode, Magento removes existing generated files and will regenerate them on the fly. Make sure that your user has write permissions for `var` and `pub/static`. Do not delete the whole directories manually because at least the `.htaccess` files must be present in developer mode and they will not be regenerated.

Read more about permission setup in the docs: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple and easy way to **Enable Developer Mode in Magento 2**.

Run the following line of command.

```
bin / magento deploy : mode : set developer
```

That's it.

You can also check your current mode by running this command.

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

It will display a message like this.

```
Current application mode: {mode}
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps to set the developer mode manually:

1. open `app/etc/env.php`
2. Set `'MAGE_MODE'` to `'developer'`

Comment: php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer