# Magento 2.2.0 upgrade, error attribute type is not allowed

Tags: attributes, magento2.2.0

> I was able to upgrade a Magento store from 2.1.6 to 2.2.0. The backend
>   is working very good, but I am encountering an exception on the front
>   office.
>
> The exception message says: Element 'block', attribute 'type': The
>   attribute 'type' is not allowed.
>
> The whole situation is described in the next post from GitHub:
>   https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11839
>
> I'm new in Magento. Could give me a link which describes from where
>   should I remove the invalid type attribute or other attributes or from
>   where can I refactor it?

Comment: It looks you're messing the setup array. Share the full exception, preferably with the code part here.

Comment: This is a part of code: 

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'type': The attribute 'type' is not allowed.
Line: 684

Element 'block', attribute 'type': The attribute 'type' is not allowed.
Line: 692

Same code repeats on multiple lines (699, 732, 737, 748, 753).

After that I get multiple lines with:
Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom

/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those lines are most likely ones in your layout XMLs:

```
Element 'block', attribute 'type': The attribute 'type' is not allowed.
Line: 776

Element 'block', attribute 'type': The attribute 'type' is not allowed.
Line: 783

Element 'block', attribute 'type': The attribute 'type' is not allowed.
Line: 816
```

Most likely in layout XMLs you have declarations like

```
<block type="..."
```

Which does not correspond to lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd and need to be replaced to

```
<block class="..."
```

Comment: You were right. There was about layout XMLs. But, as expected, I have encountered the following error on a custom module:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface TemplateMonster\FilmSlider\Api\SliderRepositoryInterface

I think I should add a new preference code block in di.xml.

Comment: Normally preferences should be added by modules which introduced new interfaces.

Please mark my answer as appropriate if initial issue is solved by suggested approach so that it can help others. If problem with SliderRepositoryInterface will be hard to solve, post it as another question.

Comment: I have solved that problem also. Thank you for all your support!

Comment: @Iulian, what was the fix you did? Running into the same error with the Templatemonster/FilmSlider..

Answer (score 0):

You are in 'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer' mode. You need to switch to 'MAGE_MODE' => 'default.
[Switch to the developer mode Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152233/switch-to-the-developer-mode-magento-2)
[image]